# yugabyte audit logs doesn't show in tserver logs

Tags: pgadmin-4, audit-logging, yugabytedb

I've enabled audit logs in yugabyte following instructions here: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/secure/audit-logging/audit-logging-ysql/

To test it, I ran the create table command (in pgadmin4) and I saw the expected audit log in the query terminal for e.g

```
NOTICE:  AUDIT: SESSION,2,1,DDL,CREATE TABLE,TABLE,public.employees,
"create table employees ( empno int, ename text, address text, salary int,
account_number text );",<not logged>
CREATE TABLE
```

However when I try to find the same log snippets in tserver log files, I don't see any entries which would confirm that my audit loggings are working. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: How did you enable it? Can you please paste the full command that you're running the db?

Comment: I enabled the flags via UI. In the YB admin console, go to the universe, select Actions->Edit flags-> 
Add ysql_pg_conf_csv flag with values ysql_pg_conf_csv="pgaudit.log='DDL',pgaudit.log_level=NOTICE,pgaudit.log_client=ON"
Then do a rolling restart. 
We are using 2.11.2 ver of YB

Comment: Did you check the .postgresql logs?

Comment: Checked. Nothing in pg logs

Comment: Actually I did find it in the postgresql log files. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Found it in the postgres log file.